# NoConvergence: WCS all world to pix

Tags: python, astropy, fits

I'm trying to convert some RA and Dec for objects I have in a .fits image into pixel values but every time I run WCS.all_world to pix I get the following error:

```
NoConvergence: 'WCS.all_world2pix' failed to converge to the requested accuracy.
After 2 iterations, the solution is diverging at least for one input point.
```

How do I avoid this? I've tried changing the tolerance but nothing seems to help.

This is the code i'm using:

```
coordinates_ID = zip(ID, RA, Dec)  
pixRA = []
pixDec = []

    #read in the fits file
insciim = fits.open('/home/myname/image.fits')

#working from a copy to avoid overwriting the images
sciim = np.copy(insciim)

#getting the header from the fits file
header = sciim[0].header
header["CTYPE1"] = "RA---TAN-SIP"
header["CTYPE2"] = "DEC--TAN-SIP"

w = wcs.WCS(insciim[0].header)

for i in coordinates_ID:
    pixra, pixdec = w.all_world2pix(i[1], i[2], 1)
    pixRA.append(pixra)
    pixDec.append(pixdec)


test = (pixRA, pixDec)

size = (200, 200)

cut = Cutout2D(sciim[0].data, test, size).data

plt.imshow(cut, origin='lower', cmap='viridis')
plt.colorbar()

img_file = "/home/myname/test.fits"
img_hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(cut, header=sciimheader)
img_hdu.writeto(img_file, overwrite=True)
```

I must state that coordinates_id is 3 zipped tables (like three lists) of the coordinates of objects in my image and the corresponding names. Can anyone spot what could cause me to get the error i'm getting?

Comment: Could you say a little more about what kind of data you're working with?  Since it's a FITS file perhaps you could include the header in your question, as well as the exact code you ran.

Comment: @Iguananaut updated! I didn't include the header as it is huge but this is the code i'm using. Its fairly short so I dont know why it isn't working.

Comment: You can also add just a portion of the header.  I'm not sure exactly how to explain what parts to include, but at least the first 10 keywords or so (which typically describe the format of the data) as well as the parts relevant to the WCS (most of them start with `C`, like `CTYPE` as well as `CRVAL`, `CRPIX`, `CDELT`, `CROTA`, etc.  That, or if you don't mind providing a link to download the file that could help too.

Comment: I don't think this is part of the real problem, but it's still not useful: `#working from a copy to avoid overwriting the images`
`sciim = np.copy(insciim)`.  Here `insciim` is just a read-only handle to the FITS file, so you can't "overwrite" the original data anyways.  `np.copy()` is for copying single Numpy arrays, but instead you're passing it an `HDUList` object.  `HDUList` is like a a Python `list` of HDU objects, so the only effect of this line is to convert the `HDUList` to a Numpy array of HDU objects, in effect making it less useful.  Just drop that line.

Comment: Your code example is also incomplete because I don't see where the variable `sciimheader` comes from, nor `ID`, `RA`, and `Dec`.  It's possible you are passing some coordinates that are outside the domain of the image but it's impossible to say without seeing a more complete, reproducible example.

Comment: Also what, if any, are the original `CTYPE1` and `CTYPE2` in the header.  You seem to be setting them manually for some reason?

Comment: Finally (and with apologies for the comment spam) while I also don't think this is the main problem, please note that [`all_world2pix`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.wcs.WCS.html#astropy.wcs.WCS.all_world2pix) can work directly on arrays.  So instead of looping over all your coordinates and calling `all_world2pix` one by one, you can apply it vastly more efficiently as a vectorized operation by passing an array for each coordinate (e.g. your `RA` and `Dec` arrays in their entirety) along with an origin.  This will return a single array of all your pixel coordinates.